# multithreading dispute on local variables

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2008, thread-safety

I had implemented a few methods that were being handled by individual background threads. I understand the complexity of doing things this way but when I tested the results it all seemed fine. Each thread accesses the same variables at times and there is maximum of 5 threads working at any given time and I guess I should have used synchlock but my question is whether there can be any way the threads could have been executing the processes without overwriting the variable contents. I was under the impression that each thread was allocated a site in memory for that variable and even though it is named the same, in memory it is a different location mapped with a specific thread, right? so if there were collisions you should be getting an error that it cannot access that variable if it were used by another thread.

Am I wrong on this?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing "processes" and "threads". Normally, the memory spaces for processes are completely separate. But threads share the same memory space. Multiple threads accessing the same memory will not cause any kind of errors, no. They'll just overwrite each other's data unless you use atomic operations for reading/writing the values.

Comment: @Eric Giguere - You should make your comment into an answer so you can get upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are talking about *local* variables of a function - no, each thread has its own copy of those on its stack.
- If you are talking about *member* variables of a class being accessed from different threads  - yes, you need to protect them (unless they are read-only)

Comment: I guess I was wrong...I had one global variable being accessed within the threading functions and this could be the source of my troubles...thanks

Comment: Yes, globals are the first suspicion in a multithreaded mess.